# Magento show wrong image when products doesn't have one

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, product-images, ce-1.8.1.0, placeholder

I have a problem with products with no image.
I have set the Product Image Placeholders in the backend at

> System > Configurations > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders

It works well with the majority of products with no image.

But often it happens that instead showing the placeholder, Magento shows a random product's image.

Tracking the problem I realised that the catalog media cache has this wrong photo, even when the backend shows that the product has no photo at all. This is an example path:

> /media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/483x398/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/7

I cleared all the caches and the wrong image is regenerated again. The only solution I could find is: select the product in the backend, and without changing anything, hit the "save" button.

I hope I explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a core issue. You can read about it, and also fix it from the official Magento2 GitHub:

MAGETWO-53036: [GITHUB] Base image placeholder issue #4549 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b065cd3e7201c1f7b0b45efe29020662d15ad9f1)

Comment: It's a similar problem, but not the same. In my case a random photo from a random product is showing, not an old placeholder. Also the solution linked is for Magento2, I'm using Magento 1.8. But it seems to be a similar issue, maybe it have a similar solution, thanks.

Comment: Sorry!! I hope you find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue in Magento 2.1.6.

Yes, for individual product you can just save the product in admin without changing anything.

If you need to do this for all products at once, you can use the following command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This will take some time to complete as it creates cache images for all products.

Comment: It's good to know i'm not alone! It's a good workaround but apparently there's no "bin/magento" in 1.8. But I could make a script myself. For now I add a generic image in all my products with no photo, a "manual placeholder", if you will. Thanks!